# Need to get record in single row in SSRS ?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using SSRS with column grouping.

I and getting the records like below. Months are getting by using column grouping.

ID  Jan Feb Mar
11  0   2   0
11  1   0   0
11  0   0   5

I want to get output like
ID  Jan Feb Mar
11  1   2   5

Kindly Assist ?

Comment: can you show the query you're using to retrieve the data

Comment: So you want to `SELECT` the `MAX` values for each month column and `GROUP BY` the first column? Have you tried literally anything?

Comment: Need to achieve this in ssrs

Comment: Data coming from query and we are using column grouping for dynamically display the data. Please assist.

Comment: Start with the query, see [SQL Group By Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for help. Then try to get that to run in SSRS, see [Reporting Services Tutorials (SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-tutorials-ssrs). We expect you to make an attempt to solve your own problem, not to dump your requirements/work on the community and us to do the whole thing for you or provide a step-by-step walk though (that is what tutorials are for).

Answer (score 0):

you should throw sample data.one data just isn't enough

```
declare @T table(ID int,Jan int, Feb int, Mar int)
insert into @T VALUES
(11, 0, 2, 0)
,(11, 1, 0, 0)
,(11, 0, 0, 5)
select t.id,t.Jan,t1.Feb 
,t2.Mar
from @t t
LEFT join @t t1
on t.id=t1.id
LEFT join @t t2
on t.id=t2.id
where t.jan>0
and t1.Feb>0
and t2.Mar>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have grouped on column.
Right click on the cells which contain values go to column group -> group properties and on group expression add the field on which you want to group it like month and do the same for all.